# Square matrix whose sum of squared elements equals 1.

Tags: matrices, sums-of-squares

I'm doing some applied work where I've come across examples that involve real valued square matrices that hold the following property, which expressed using tensor notation is

$$A_{ij}A_{ij} = 1$$

And equivalently with summation notation

$$\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N A_{ij}*A_{ij}=1$$

Are such matrices known as anything special?

Comment: Do you mean the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) is $1$?

Comment: Maybe either matrices that are their own inverses, or square roots of unity/idetntity?

Comment: Are the entries real or complex, or in some other field?

Comment: @A.G That indeed matches the operation, so what would it mean to have a Frobenius norm of 1? Seems like there's a related question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131392/why-one-would-want-to-normalize-a-matrix-by-dividing-it-by-its-frobenius-norm)

Comment: @RobertIsrael good clarification, they're real valued.

Comment: @jxramos Unfortunately nothing particular interesting about the matrix (like structure) can be said except very general inequality bounds on the singular values etc Any matrix can be made to have the norm 1 after normalization with a scalar. What can you say about a vector if you know it has length one? Here is the same.

Comment: @A.G. you're right, I think I would up finding some funny behavior in Matlab that made me wonder if there was special properties to these matrices.